# Cannot use linear interpolation with matplotlib griddata function

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

The following code is a simplified version of what I am having trouble with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import numpy as np

def grid(x, y, z, resX=100, resY=100):
    xi = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), resX)
    yi = np.linspace(np.min(y), np.max(y), resY)
    #Z    = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
    Z    = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
    return X, Y, Z

data = np.random.randint(200,size = (40,20))

X = np.arange(40)
Y = np.arange(20)

x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
z = np.array(data)

X, Y, Z = grid(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel(), resX=50, resY=50)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(data)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(Z)
plt.show()
```

As long as I use the commented line

```
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
```

instead of

```
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
```

everything is working well. As soon as I launch the code with linear interpolation instead I get a

```
raise ValueError("output grid must have constant spacing"
ValueError: output grid must have constant spacing when using interp='linear'
```

So how can it be, that np.linspace() does not produce constant spacing or what am I missing? 
(Obviously my real data are much more complex than the one used in the example and not equally spaced so there is a real need for using griddata!)

Comment: :The code runs fine with gruddata , interp='linear''..

Comment: which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: I am on numpy 1.8.2 and matplotlib 1.3.1. However a few minutes ago I came across this old and identical question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338649/mlab-griddata-bug. Seems that he had the same problem and could not solve it in the end (but switched to scipy.griddata instead).

Comment: :Well, try it then ans see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upgrade to matplotlib 1.4.3 and numpy 1.9.2 did the trick. Now linear interpolation is working fine, but originally used natural neighbor was not working any more

```
raise RuntimeError("To use interp='nn' (Natural Neighbor "
RuntimeError: To use interp='nn' (Natural Neighbor interpolation) in griddata, natgrid must be installed.  Either install it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits, or use interp='linear' instead.
```

I upgraded (Ubuntu 14.04) via

```
# Install libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev

# Upgrade to matplotlib 1.4 using PIP
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

After manually installing **natgrid** (http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/) all my problems seem solved!

@George: THANKS